# i have a telegram messanger bot that i made with telethon how can i use an inline button to get input?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/start'))
async def send_welcome(event):
    await event.reply('hi, il send your message to my admin')

@bot.on(events.NewMessage())
async def hey(event):
    await event.message.forward_to(admin)
    sender = event.sender_id
    await bot.send_message(admin,'click to answer',buttons=[Button.inline('answer',data ='answer/'+str(sender))])
    await event.reply('sent')

with bot:
   bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

i want the button to get a message from me and send it to the bot user when i click on it
what should i di?